# How to apply texture onto model

Tags: modeling, rendering

Sorry for the question but I'm new to blender and have recently found this gun model on Sketchfab that I would like to use https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/ak47-with-scope-d4d9720f3677485b958ceecc02f7965c. After downloading it and opening up the .fbx file in Blender, I was shown the same model but with very weird textures.[image]

The textures folder contains the following files but I am unsure on how to apply them to the gun model in Blender. [image]

Comment: Yes, I have 5 different texture maps for each texture, how can I tell what type each map is.

Comment: If this is a question: (?) the file names are actually pretty bad and do not follow any convention so the only thing you can do is asking the author to be on the safe side. Otherwise just test them, My guess: MT = Metallic, NR = Normal, BC = Color, R = Roughness.